# NEO4J - ORDER BY not recognized as sub-clause instruction but as plain text

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When using the following query in Neo4J

```
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b)
where  a.wordName contains 'metabolism'
RETURN a,b,apoc.create.vRelationship(a,'REL_COUNT',{amount:count(r)},b) as rel limit 1
ORDER BY count(r)
```

I get the following error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'D' (line 4, column 3 (offset: 147))
"ORDER BY count(r);"
   ^                `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have swapped the `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` clauses, `ORDER BY` goes first, then `LIMIT`.

This should work:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b)
where  a.wordName contains 'metabolism'
RETURN a,b,apoc.create.vRelationship(a,'REL_COUNT',{amount:count(r)},b) as rel
ORDER BY count(r) 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: THANKS, František - The solution to move the limit worked, but revealed another error:
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: In a WITH/RETURN with DISTINCT or an aggregation, it is not possible to access variables declared before the WITH/RETURN

which I had to correct by adding the variable rel_counter in the RETURN clause


MATCH (a)-[r]-(b)
where  a.wordName contains 'metabolism'
RETURN a,b,apoc.create.vRelationship(a,'REL_COUNT',{amount:count(r)},b) as rel , count(r) as rel_counter
ORDER BY rel_counter DESC
LIMIT 1